# How to fix gunicorn.service: Failed to load environment files: Is a directory

Tags: python, software-center, application-development, nginx, django

When i run

```
sudo journalctl -u gunicorn
```

I get:

```
Oct 14 12:49:22 my-server-thing systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed to load environment files: Is a directory
Oct 14 12:49:22 my-server-thing systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed to run 'start' task: Is a directory
Oct 14 12:49:22 my-server-thing systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Oct 14 12:49:22 my-server-thing systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
```

I suppose something doesn’t add up with my directories. I have `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` which is:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myname
Group=myname
EnvironmentFile=/home/myname/myapp/env
WorkingDirectory=/home/myname/myapp
ExecStart=/home/myname/myapp/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myapp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
The directories I’m working in are as follows.
```

`myapp/` has my requirements.txt file, my env, and another app/ dir. Within myapp/app, I have manage.py and another app/ env. Within myapp/app/app, I have settings.py and wsgi.py.

Also when I run

```
nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I get

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2020/10/15 10:32:57 [warn] 31742#31742: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2020/10/15 10:32:57 [emerg] 31742#31742: unknown directive "mydomainname.co.uk" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/flaskapp.conf:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the `nginx -t` components are because you need to run that with `sudo nginx -t` - but your configuration (conf.d) isn't a full server configuration likely.  Include the config for your flask app, I think you have multiple things going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

`EnvironmentFile=/home/myname/myapp/env` should be a file not as some may expect it to be a folder.

There seems a convention conflict here, between web projects and systemd.